# set TYPO3 into maintenance mode

Tags: typo3, typoscript, maintenance-mode

I added the following code to the `localconf.php`:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['adminOnly'] = '2';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageUnavailable_force'] = '1';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageUnavailable_handling'] = 'http://www.somedomain.com/maintenance';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageUnavailable_handling_statheader'] = 'HTTP/1.0 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['devIPmask'] = '127.0.0.1,::1,1.2.3.4';
```

1.2.3.4 is my IP address. http://www.somedomain.com/maintenance is on another webserver (not the webserver where the TYPO3 installation is). I get the following message `Moved Permanently - The document has moved here`. How do I make the correct redirect? I tried to put a html-file on the webserver where the TYPO3 installation is, but than I get

> Oops, an error occured!
>
> Reason: This page is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Additionally, http://www.domain.com/maintenance.html was not
>   found while trying to retrieve the error document.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The value in `pageUnavailable_handling` will be fetched by TYPO3, parse and then returned to the browser. Thus if you want to point to another server, then you either have to send a `30x` header and do a redirect inside the HTML document or you have to setup a redirect rule within .htaccess.
I would do the later.

Comment: I'll try it the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

REDIRECT should solve your problem.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageUnavailable_handling'] = 'REDIRECT:http://www.somedomain.com/maintenance';
```

Other options are READFILE for static html pages or USER_FUNCTION for, well user functions ;-)